# How can prove $KA=KT$ (IMO problem)

Tags: geometry

Let $\omega$ be the circumcircle of a triangle $ABC$. Denote by $M$ and $N$ the midpoints of the sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, and denote by $T$ the midpoint of the arc $BC$ of $\omega$ not containing $A$. The circumcircles of the triangles $AMT$ and $ANT$ intersect the perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $AB$ at points $X$ and $Y$, respectively; assume that $X$ and $Y$ lie inside the triangle $ABC$. The lines $MN$ and $XY$ intersect at $K$. Prove that $KA=KT$

This is IMO Shortlist 2013 problem .

[image]

maybe I think we can use Law of sines to prove it.
$$\dfrac{a}{\sin{A}}=\dfrac{b}{\sin{B}}=\dfrac{c}{\sin{C}}$$
so
I think we can prove $$\Delta KMA \cong \Delta KXT$$

But I can't.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that this boils down to proving that $MNYX$ is an isosceles trapezoid having its bases parallel to $AT$ and its diagonals intersecting in the circumcenter of $ABC$.

This is quite trivial since $AT$ is the angle bisector of $\widehat{A}$ and the centers of the circumcircles of $AMT$ and $ANT$ both lie on the perpendicular bisector of $AT$, hence both $MX$ and $NY$ are parallel to $AT$ by the circular inversion with respect to the circumcircle of $AMN$ ($O$ belongs to that circumcircle).